# CSS/HTML - Bootstrap dropdown, with same class, positioned under different links

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a problem with the position of my bootstrap dropdown class.

So, I have these two dropdown links in my table:

Whenever you click the down arrows, a dropdown will appear. The problem is, that the dropdown box, is always positioned to appear at a **fixed** position, and not next to each arrow. *(Imagine if the table is example 100 rows - then the last dropdown, will appear in the same place as the first)*

The problem is like this:

1. The arrows which holds the dropdown.

[image]

2. The dropdown will **always** be at the top arrow position - even though you clicked on the second dropdown arrow.

[image]

Please see **this bootply for the code and preview:** [Bootply Preview](http://www.bootply.com/QNV6nCrk9v)

Comment: check is this what you want http://www.bootply.com/wqBksx2Uvy

Comment: @rjdmello Yes! Please submit as an answer, including the changes you made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check is this what you want [bootply.com/wqBksx2Uvy](http://www.bootply.com/wqBksx2Uvy)

add dropdown class to td as

```
<td class="dropdown">
```

remove ref-moreinfo

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
```

Comment: Your solution also removes the custom style .more-refinfo. I will need this style for the dropdown

Comment: add that style with different style name

Comment: but if I have 100 of these records, I would need 100 of those styles. Doesn't work